# Is this notification page for my taxi-booking/sharing app clear enough?

Tags: usability, gui-design, mobile-application

I've recently redone the UI wireframing for my taxi booking/sharing app's notification screen. On the notifications screen, the user receives updates on any taxi share requests or messages they receive.

Is it easier to read to tell what the requests are for on the new notification screen? What other features can I add to make it clearer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new mockup has some good points but regrouping the notifications by categories makes it hard to order chronologically.

I also think you shouldn't manage messages as notifications. They are too different and having a notification like "Frank sent you a message" is not really relevant.

There is a problem you'll be facing with the current design. Let's say I requested two taxis, the first for today and the other for tomorow. Notifications should notice me that

> Jack wants to share the cab you requested today (Origin -> Destination)

I think you should mix the two versions to make it works.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh3WBe.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You may want to provide some more background on the issue that users are solving (ie. cab with strangers going the same way, leaving exact same place, etc.)

It may make more sense to keep it how you had originally with a stream of activity relative to that user. So your first screen is arranged chronologically and lists activity:

## **< Activity ⟳**

- Paul **Said lorem ipsum...** *12:35 am*
- Gavin **wants to share a cab** *12:25 am*

And your screen for each user, you have your activity stream (a la Tinder):

## **< Paul ⟳**

- Paul : **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed consectetur.** / 12:35 am
- Paul : **Requested a cab share.** / 12:34 am
- **Yes, we're going somewhere too** / 12:33 am : You
- Paul : **We're going somewhere, you?** / 12:32 am

Comment: Welcome on ux.stackexchange SwankyLegg ! You can make quick mockups using the tool provided by the editor when posting an answer :)